# In AngularJS, Which Entity Renders Templates When Used in Multiple Controllers?

Tags: angularjs

I am rendering a template via two methods: 1) fill out a form; 2) provide an id and data is fetched from the server.

If `FormController` -- a controller -- handles form input, `IdController` -- also a controller -- handles id input, `$dataProvider` -- a service -- handles the fetching, what type of entity should do the template rendering in order to keep it DRY?

Answer (score 0):

For my current project we need to have dynamic forms, which can be created and maintained by users in a super friendly way. You can see a plunker of it in action over [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/L0n4qi?p=preview).

For rendering the form I used a form-renderer directive, which loops through the schema and builds up the html containing all kinds other directives (general field html, specific field html, generic validation, ...).

Note: maybe it's better to not use the name FormController; it's already used by [Angular](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3aform.FormController).

Comment: Thanks @null, I will take a look.  (fyi - the controller names are illustrative, but thanks for the tip!)